# Unable to fetch data using HttpWebRequest or HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, exception, web-scraping, httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack

I am trying to make web scraper in C# for NSE. The code works with other sites but when ran on https://www.nseindia.com/ it gives error - **An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to read data from the transport connection: Operation timed out.**

I have tried with two different approaches Try1() & Try2().
Can anyone please tell what I am missing in my code?

```
class Program
{
    public void Try1() {
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

        web.UserAgent = GetUserAgent();

        web.PostResponse = (request, response) =>
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                statusCode = response.StatusCode;
                Console.WriteLine("Status Code: " + statusCode);
            }
        };

        Task<HtmlDocument> task = web.LoadFromWebAsync(GetURL());
        HtmlDocument document = task.Result;
    }

    public void Try2() {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(GetURL());
        request.UserAgent = GetUserAgent();
        request.Accept= "*/*;";

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(request.GetResponse()))
        {
            HttpStatusCode code = response.StatusCode;
            if (code == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
                    htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
                    htmlDoc.Load(streamReader);
                    Console.WriteLine("Document Loaded.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private string GetURL() {
        // return "https://html-agility-pack.net/";
        return "https://www.nseindia.com/";
    }

    private string GetUserAgent() {
        return "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are lack of headers towards `Accept` and others so it couldn't response back.
Besides that, I would recommend you using `HttpClient` instead of `HttpWebRequest`

```
public static async Task GetHtmlData(string url)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(url)))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml, charset=UTF-8, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36 OPR/67.0.3575.137");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

        using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            using (var decompressedStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(decompressedStream))
            {
                var result = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
                htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
                htmlDoc.LoadHtml(result);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                Console.WriteLine("Document Loaded.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Use it by

```
await GetHtmlData("https://www.nseindia.com/");
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked like a charm. I am new to request/response in c#, if possible can you please give me reference links where I learn in depth about it?

Comment: The scraping technique depends on each website operation and search it if it's quite weird. From my experience, I always inspect the network request in Chrome (F12), then bring these headers, cookie, parameters and body request to test it on Postman. Then apply it with `HttpClient`, [Flurl](https://flurl.dev) are enough.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same for the "https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/currencies" but SelectSinglenodes returns a Null for values in table. I would like to try out the solution you have suggested here. I am using ASP.Net website. Is it possible to have a code without asynchronous method?

Comment: @giparekh You might call `GetHtmlData("https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/currencies").Wait();` if you would like to run synchronously

Comment: @TấnNguyên are there any changes required in the method?

Comment: @giparekh Currently no changes, I have tested your site, it worked well. Whereas the default HtmlAgilityPack.Load might get error because the site show "Are you robot?"

Comment: @TấnNguyên Thanks a lot. This works perfectly for me. Now the major issue facing is all the span has same class name and no id assign to them. How can i get the specific span value from this website? I need to get the currency value from the table. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: @TấnNguyên Additionally, i have tried to fetch the data from "https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500.html" <td id="quotesFuturesProductTable1_ESZ0_last"> which is not working. Any idea why is it returning null here?

Comment: @giparekh The table have their own order of tr and td, so the xpath might like".//td[3]/tr[@data-type = 'value']"

Comment: @giparekh I see your new site is continuous loading by javascript, as normal request not supported. Then you have no choice without simulate a [WebBroswer](http://davidgiard.com/2018/06/20/UsingHTMLAgilityPackToParseAWebPage.aspx) to get this.

The conversation is becoming longer and could be removed by moderator because a little bit outscope, if you get more stucks, create a new thread and I will come!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217881/discussion-between-giparekh-and-tn-nguyen).

Comment: @TấnNguyên when I try to use the website https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ms?p=ms&_guc_consent_skip=1596806986 , it gives me an error System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). Please check and advise.